# When I save the code on VS code editor, auto change code format

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am coding on React Native.
I downloaded the code from Git
I will share my code
Before saving
[image]

After saving
[image]

I already uninstalled all extensions
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I already uninstalled all extensions on Vs code

Comment: And what is `editor.formatOnSave` set to?

Comment: can you send a list from your vscode extensions here in comments?

Comment: Hi Jarmod , where can I find the setting option?
Hi Amir, no extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable ESLint:

View → Command Pallete → Open Workspace Settings → add: **"eslint.enable": false**

Or

Disable ESLint Auto Fix:

View → Command Pallete → Open Workspace Settings → add: **"eslint.autoFixOnSave": false**

Comment: Thanks for your reply
where is the settings.json?